# No visible @interface for UIButton declares the selector"setbookmarkState

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Declared BOOL

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL BookmarkState;
```

When using the BOOL for UIButton added on navigationbar using storyboard

```
[_bookmarkbtn setBookmarkState:NO];
```

then gets ARC Semantic issue

```
No visible @interface for UIButton declares the selector"setbookmarkState
```

EDIT:

PageViewController h file

```
@interface PageViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource> 

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL BookmarkState;

@end
```

PageViewController m file

```
@interface PageViewController () {


BOOL BookmarkState;

}



@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bookmarkbtn;


@implementation PageViewController
```

Comment: try `[_bookmarkbtn setBookmarkState:NO];` ?

Comment: Show more code for the class definition and the bookmarkbtn definition.

Comment: Is this your own class?  UIButton has no such property.  If you declared your own subclass of UIButton and are using it in a storyboard then you need to set the "custom class" property in the identity inspector to the name of your subclass... otherwise the storyboard will use a standard UIButton for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIButton has no property called `bookmarkState`. 
If you want to disable your button `bookmarkbtn`, use `[_bookmarkbtn setEnabled:NO];`
Or if you want to deselect it, use `[_bookmarkbtn setSelected:NO];`
Or if you want to unhighlight it, use `[_bookmarkbtn setHighlighted:NO];`

If you want to set the bookmarkState to `NO`, use `[self setBookmarkState:NO];`

Edit: it seems like you've named the booleans differently (one with lowercase, and one with uppercase) so my question is - are you certain of what are you doing / of what are you trying to accomplish?

Pardon me if it will sound rude or disrespectful, but calling setbookmarkState on UIButton is clearly showing that you aren't quite sure of how to do something you that you need.
Also, XCode should give you an error stating that no visible interface for `UIButton` declares the selector `setbookmbarState:`

First of all - as stated, UIButton has no property `bookmarkState`.
Then, calling an autosynthesized setter method always implies that you use `setMyProperty`, not `setmyProperty`, or `setmyproperty`. It's weird how you got it to run :)

Good luck!

Comment: Typed lowercase by mistake. typo mistake.